# Serve a pre-compressed gzipped file in express.js (not with compress() )

Tags: node.js, express, webpack, gzip

I'm looking to serve a gzipped file, however all approaches i have currently followed or come up with don't seem to have any effect.

I have a gzipped file with a gz extension in my static assets folder.

Currently I have used the following:

```
router.get("*.js", (req, res, next) => {

    // only if file exists, the substr is to remove /assets in front
    if (!fs.existsSync(`/app/service/public/${req.url.substr(7)}.gz`)) {
        return next();
    }

    console.log(`${req.url} -> ${req.url}.gz`);

    req.url = `${req.url}.gz`;
    res.set("Content-Encoding", "gzip");
    res.set("Content-Type", "text/javascript");
    next();
});

router.use("/assets", express.static("/app/service/public"));
```

The file exists and the directory is correctly set, but for someway it doesn't seem to serve the gzip file (neither does it add the correct headers)

Comment: Works okay for me. The only thing you have to look out for is that you declare the "rewriting" middleware _before_ the static middleware, and are you sure that `__dirname` is the correct directory for the static assets?

Comment: I added an exta check to see if the file exists, I have updated my code with this check. When i define the rewriting middleware after the static middleware, the request doesn't print me a log statement

Comment: Let's take a step back: what URL are you requesting, and in which directory is the file that you want to return?

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late reply. the url I'm requesting is *assets/static/js/bundle.js*, which i change to *assets/static/js/bundle.js.gz* (which exists).
The file is located in *public/assets/static/js/bundle.js.gz* (which also exists, and i verified that through the check above). I have updated my code above to reflect my directory setup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your static middleware setup, which is pointing to the wrong path.

Given the information in your comment:

- the `.js.gz` files are stored in `../public/assets/static/js/`
- you are requesting `/assets/static/js/bundle.js`, which should use the file called `bundle.js.gz` in aforementioned directory

This means that you need to use one of two static middleware configurations:

```
app.use('/assets', express.static(__dirname + '/../public/assets'));
```

Or:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public/'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply, i have updated my original question to represent better my directory structure. However i don't seem to get the paths correct.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [express-static-gzip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-static-gzip) which does exactly what you asked for.

```
app.use("/", expressStaticGzip("/my/rootFolder/"));
```

Also, you may specify different options, but the default will work in your case.